# Oracle APEX - get workspace for current app

Tags: oracle-apex

I need workspace name of the current app to access RESTful API.

Is there any substitution string for this? Or what is easiest way to get workspace name of the current app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of those for the ID:

```
Bind variable -> :WORKSPACE_ID
PL/SQL -> V('WORKSPACE_ID')
Substitution string -> &WORKSPACE_ID.
SYS_CONTEXT variable - > SELECT ... WHERE workspace_id = SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION', 'WORKSPACE_ID')
```

And to get the name:

```
select workspace from apex_workspaces where workspace_id = :WORKSPACE_ID
```

or

```
select workspace from apex_workspaces where workspace_id = SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION', 'WORKSPACE_ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from apex_applications
```

You need `apex_administrator_role` to obtain not only current schema applications.
...And if you are new you need to be aware of administration role implications.

Comment: When I run this query I only get one app. But I know there are at least 6 apps in this workspace. I am administrator in this workspace.

Comment: did you have checked that you have apex_administrator_role ?
 grant apex_administrator_role to <your_user>;

Comment: I tested this select on two instances. I don't have this role on neither of them. On one instance I get all applications, but problem is this second one on which I need this functionallity. My coworker run this query with sys user and got the same result as I did with my.

Comment: This role is available since apex 4.1 . SYS should see and can grant this role. If it is greater than 4.1 and SYS not see apex_administrator_role try to validate your apex installation. Update - 3.2 has this role too https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e12510/apex_instance.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
select workspace
from apex_applications
where 1=1
  and application_id = :app_id
```

You don't need to `apex_administrator_role` as another answer suggests unless the parsing schema is not assigned to the current workspace.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't find solution what is wrong with **apex_applications**, so we used workaround with **apex_040200.wwv_flow_authorized** which is working correctly for us.